# Usage of the verb "risk"

Tags: word-usage

> A plea-bargaining Navy lawyer risks both career and **prison** If he exposes the commanding ... (From a synopsis of *A Few Good Men by Johnny Screenwriter*)

When we risk something we have we migh lose it but how we can risk something we don't have like prison. Why is "risk" used in "risk prison"?

Comment: See sense 2 of the verb [here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/risk_2). Does the sentence make sense now? Please always look up words or phrases [in multiple dictionaries](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/739/3395) if you're struggling to understand something before posting the question here. If you still don't understand even after looking up the word, when posting the question here include the research you've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to English Language Learners Stack Exchange!

We usually use the verb risk in two senses as follows:

- If you risk something valuable or important, you act in a way that might result 
  in that thing being lost or damaged.  So if you risk your career, it means your career 
  might be lost or affected.
- If you risk something bad or unpleasant (such as prison in the sentence), it 
  means  that you do something that might result in that thing happening or 
  affecting you.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as:

> A plea-bargaining Navy lawyer risks both career and **((the possibility of) going to)** prison if he exposes the commanding ...

The words in parentheses are optional and can be omitted without losing the meaning, as long as there is sufficient context.